# Access Dynamic Component using Angular Decorators

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I am new to Angular 6

I just want to ask my question regarding **Angular Dynamic Component Creation**.

I have created dynamic component and added it to the **View Container** see my code snippet.

```
//dynamic Component Creation

  private taskCompList=[];
  var componentFactory=this.componentResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TaskInputComponent);      
  let taskInputComp=this.taskListView.createComponent(componentFactory);
  let taskCompInstance=taskInputComp.instance;
  taskCompInstance.selfRef=taskInputComp;

 //adding created component to array
 this.taskCompList.push(taskCompInstance);
```

In above code I have captured the dynamically created component in **taskCompList** array.

Later, I have the iterated the taskCompArray to get bean from created child Component

```
//itreating array to get component values
private taskModel=[];
this.taskCompList.forEach(taskInputComp=>
{
//getting childcomponent bean 
this.taskModel.push(taskInputComp.getTaskBean());
console.info(taskInputComp.getTaskBean().taskName);
});
```

This one perfectly works.

But my question is instead of **capturing the child component in array and iterating it**. Is there is any other possible solution to handle the created child components.

More specifically using any **decorators**  like **@ViewChild, @ViewChildren** to get child component values (Child component bean in my scenario).

Comment: if you are new to angular, and you are already using dynamic component creation, you are not working with angular like you should. I suggest to find another way of accomplishing what you want, by using the template syntax in angular. This way you don't lose the AOT capabilities and makes your code more maintainable and testable. Rule of thumb, never use dynamic components. You will not need them 99.99% of the time

Comment: what do you mean by template syntax, Could you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: I cannot, because I don't know what you are trying to achieve with your dynamic component creation. But usually you can make it work with `*ngIf`, `[ngSwitch]`, `<ng-template>`, `<ng-content>`. I suggest reading in on these. Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have tried all these methods, My questions is specific to Dynamic Component.

Comment: To be more clear, In my first code snippet. I have added the created component object in taskCompList array so instead of capturing it in array can we able to capture it using angular decorator like @ViewChild,@ViewChildren like we do in *ngFor. approach.